# How to efficiently implement array element lookup and removal in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given a sorted array of objects, while the order is based on some object attribute. (Sorting is done via a List using Collections.sort() with a custom Comparator and then calling toArray()).

Duplicate instances of SomeObject are not allowed ("duplicates" in this regard depends on multiple attribute value in SomeObject), but it's possible that multiple instances of SomeObject have the same value for attribute1, which is used for sorting.

```
public SomeObject {
  public attribute1;
  public attribute2;
}

List<SomeObject> list = ...
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<SomeObject>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(SomeObject v1, SomeObject v2) {
    if (v1.attribute1 > v2.attribute1) {
      return 1;
    } else if (v1.attribute1 < v2.attribute1) {
      return -1;
    } else
      return 0;
  }
});
SomeObject[] array = list.toArray(new SomeObject[0]);
```

How to efficiently check whether a certain object based on some attribute is in that array while also being able to "mark" objects already found in some previous look up (e.g. simply by removing them from the array; already found objects don't need to be accessed at later time).

Without the later requirement, one could do a Arrays.binarySearch() with custom Comparator. But obviously it's not working when one want to remove objects already found.

Comment: Is the attribute that is being used to sort, the same attribute that you are searching on?

Comment: @Vivin: Yes, that's the case.

Comment: Can you have duplicate objects?

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the data in an array? Other data structures are more suited to the task if there's no particular reason they can't be used.

Comment: @JtheRocker: Yes and No: duplicates of SomeObject are not allowed, but whether two objects are equal depends on multiple attributes, but it's possible that values for attibute1, which is used for sorting and lookup may have same values.

Comment: @jacobm: The requirement above is part of some larger algorithm which works on an array for convenience and performance, so let's assume an array must be used.

Comment: "array for convenience" when there are other data structures that do exactly what you want ...

Comment: @Arian: To make it more concrete... which other data structure you suggest to efficiently access ranges of an array, e.g. between idx a and b (a <= b) and do some arraycopy of ranges? I am not aware of something "better" than plain old array.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about your requirements. There can be multiple non-equal elements that are regarded equivalent by the comparator? So just keeping a count will not be enough? When you search for elements, do you want to mark/remove all equivalent elements at once, or only one at a time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (or [TreeMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html)).

You can initialize it with your comparator; it sorts itself; look-up and removal are in logarithmic time.

You can also check for existence and remove in one step, because `remove` returns a boolean.

Comment: and what about if he want repeat elements :O ?

Comment: This also requires that `equals` and `hashCode` on the object return the hashcode of the attribute that he is using, I think.

Comment: @VivinPaliath no, it doesn't. The TreeSet will use the comparator.

Comment: @Arian The `TreeSet` will use the comparator to see if a given object exists within the set?

Comment: @VivinPaliath Yes, it has to. As the set is sorted using the comparator, there is no other way to find it.

Comment: @Adrian You are correct. If the comparator is provided, it will use that. Thanks; I was thinking of something else.

Comment: TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

Comment: @nachokk If there is a requirement for duplicate elements, there are possible workarounds (eg, sort after second attribute), or use Guavas sorted multiset http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html

Comment: "it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface." They're more like guidelines anyway ;)

Comment: TreeSet doesn't work because values of attribute1 of multiple objects may be equal.

Comment: While I am not really happy with it, because initializing a SortedMultiSet each time when working with different arrays is kind of heavy, especially when you have some large data set. But it's a possible solution to my answer anyway.

Comment: @Scholle: why not sort by your attribute in Comparator first and then use TreeSet with your someObject?

Answer (score 0):

Building on Arian's answer, you can also use [`TreeBag`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/TreeBag.html) from Apache Commons' Collections library. This is backed by a `TreeMap`, and maintains a count for repeated elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can put all the elements into some sort of linked list whose nodes are also connected in a heap form when you sort them. That way, finding an element would be log n and you can still delete the nodes in place.